# How to access github secrets key from android studio project

Tags: android, github, github-actions, github-secret

I have an android project with GitHub actions which needs some key in GitHub secrets to successfully build. I wonder how to access Github secrets key from my project code like this?

[image]

I have tried to assign the key to local properties on my yml config files ([android.yml](https://github.com/galihif/PahePremium/blob/master/.github/workflows/android.yml)) based on this [article](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/accessing-android-app-secret-from-github-actions-using-gradle/)

[image]

but it's still failed to build because BASE_URL still not detected ([workflow](https://github.com/galihif/PahePremium/actions/runs/2933872376))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the build.yml file with an additional step to put the secret into a new local.properties file but make sure this step is done after checking out the code.
the link below has all the detailed steps :

> https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/accessing-android-app-secret-from-github-actions-using-gradle/

Comment: actually, I've tried it but still doesn't work. I have added the detail in the edit